# .htaccess giving internal errors

Tags: .htaccess, html-helper

my page frequently gives errors like forbidden access or internal server error, i think the problem its because my .htaccess file configuration, here it is :

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
ErrorDocument 400 ../errors/400.html
ErrorDocument 401 ../errors/401.html
ErrorDocument 403 ../errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 ../errors/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 ../errors/500.html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.bedif\.net)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://bedif.net/$1 [R=301,L]
DirectoryIndex index.html       
order deny,allow
deny from ../tools/
deny from ../lightbox/
deny from ../errors/
deny from ../images/
```

Comment: check your apache error logs/

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. `deny from ../tools/` makes no sense at all, and all your deny from lines are causing a 500 error. The [mod_auth docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny) say the syntax for this is:

   ```
   Deny from all|host|env=[!]env-variable
   ```

   Which means it can either be a "all", a host/IP, or an environmet variable. `../tools/` is none of them. You can't put paths in a `Deny`.
2. The `ErrorDocument` directive takes either a full URL, or an absolute path to a file. Anything else, apache assumes you're giving it a specific error message. This means, if you go to a file that doesn't exist, you'll get a 404 and the page **will literally say**:

   ```
   ../errors/404.html
   ```

   as the page's message, and not the contents of the html file. Change those to absolute paths.